# how to logout programatically in iOS app using facebook sdk 4.x

Tags: ios, facebook

How to logout programatically in iOS app using `Facebook` sdk 4.x

I tried below code but its not working for `Facebook`, `iOS` SDK 4.x

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Answer (score 1):

you try this code to logout facebook.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *logMeOut = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[logMeOut logOut];
```

or

```
[FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];
[FBSDKProfile setCurrentProfile:nil];
```